# Reading two text file simultaneously in python 3.0 and extracting required string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have two text file with data similar to

file_1:

```
data1 data_1 1
data2 data_2 2
data3 data_2 2 
data2 data_4 1
data3 data_3 1 and so on....
```

and so on

file_2:

```
data1
data2 
data1
data3
data2
```

I want to get a output as

```
data1:
      > data1 data_1 1
      > data1 data_3 2

data2:
      > data2 data_2 2
      > data2 data_4 1

data3:
      > data3 data_3 1
```

and so on...

What I get from the present code:

```
data1:
      > data1 data_1 1

data2:
      > data2 data_2 2

data3:
      > data3 data_2 2
      > data2 data_4 1
      > data3 data_3 1
```

Code:

```
first_occurance = {}
    with open("folder_1/file_1", "r") as file_1:
        with open("folder_1/file_2", "r") as file_2:
            for line_1,line_2 in zip(file_1, file_2):
                only_command = line_1.split()[0]
                if only_command in line_2:
                    if only_command not in first_occurance:
                        print ("\n   " + only_command + " :\n")
                        print ("      > " + line_1.strip())
                    else:
                        print ("      > " + line_1.strip())
                    first_occurance[only_command] = only_command
```

But this doesn't work as expected as data are not formatted according to the title for example lines corresponding to `data2` are also displayed in `data3`.  Any guidance for this issue would be really helpful....

Comment: Can you describe what happens?

Comment: I edited the question.. Hope its more clear now...

Comment: Not quite, still. So what do you expect to happen with `data3`? Should that be printed below the data2 block?

Comment: Your problem is not reading from multiple files - it's how you're iterating, but it's really unclear what kind of result you're trying to get from your description.

Comment: @user3467349 I have edited it now... hope its better understandable....

Comment: @fnl Edited again hope its more clear

Comment: ...why do you have to read them simultaneously if they aren't ordered? You'll need to know the full data of one before processing the other, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you might be trying to do:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = """data1 data_1 1
data2 data_2 2
data1 data_3 2
data3 data_4 1
data2 data_3 1"""

commands = """data1
data2
data1
data3
data2"""

store = defaultdict(list)

for line, cmd in zip(data.split('\n'), commands.split('\n')):
    if line.startswith(cmd):
        store[cmd].append(line.strip())

for command in sorted(store):
    print("\n{}:".format(command))
    for l in store[command]:
        print("      >", l)
```

This produces the following output:

```
data1:
      > data1 data_1 1
      > data1 data_3 2

data2:
      > data2 data_2 2
      > data2 data_3 1

data3:
      > data3 data_4 1
```

For each line in commands (what you read from `file_2`), if the exact same line in data (`file_1`) starts with the same "command", it is stored. Incidentally, you are changing the data a lot and I am not sure we understand what you want there. It seems, file_2 is even useless or you might want to re-align your data?

Whatever, after you have stored the grouped data, you can print the groups in sorted order (data1, 2, 3...). You have to store all groups or you will have to read the file again and again for each (data) group. If you don't you get your current output - because you print the data as you receive it.

However, it seems your `file_2` data isn't needed at all, at least according to the output you want in your question. So here is the file-reading version that produces your desired output; note that it does not need to read `file_2`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

store = defaultdict(list)

with open("folder_1/file_1", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        cmd, content = line.split(' ', 1)
        store[cmd].append(line.strip())

for cmd in sorted(store):
    print("\n{}:".format(cmd))
    for line in store[cmd]:
        print("      >", line)
```

Comment: I get an error as **for line_1,line_2 in zip(file_1.split('\n'), file_2.split('\n')):
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: Because you are doing a split on the file handle/stream. Please check the update, with the code that aligns to your file reading version.

Comment: In addition, note that I don't understand why you even need to check `file_2`? It seems you are changing the assignment of your data?